# Prevent Keychain from copying an internet password to my login keychain

Tags: safari, keychain

I find that my passwords are being copied from my "bank" keychain into the login keychain every time I allow Safari to autofill the fields. How can I prevent that?

I have created a separate keychain called "bank" to store my sensitive financial account passwords. I use a different keychain password and set it to lock automatically after 5 minutes.

Comment: Short answer, its by design in Safari. All passwords saved in Safari will be stored in the default/Login keychain. I could suggest using an app (such as 1password) instead and not letting Safari manage/autofill passwords at all.

Comment: I created a Radar for this and I recently got an email from Apple (on Feb 27) that they have fixed it in a security update (presumably upcoming). The OpenRadar is here: https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4965515323768832

Answer (score 1):

This was a security bug and a fix was released today by Apple.

[About the security content of Safari 10.1](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT207600):

**Safari Login AutoFill**

> Available for:  OS X Yosemite v10.10.5, OS X El Capitan v10.11.6,
>   and macOS Sierra 10.12.4
>
> Impact: A local user may be able to access locked keychain items
>
> Description: A keychain handling issue was addressed through improved keychain item management.
>
> CVE-2017-2385: Simon Woodside of MedStack